# typescript compiles dist directory starting a compile loop

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working on a repository which is actually a monorepo. I'm trying to add a module and I want to use typescript on it. I have added a tsconfig.json file on the root of the package folder with the following config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "compileOnSave":true,
        "watch": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    ]
}
```

I have two problems with this configuration:

1) The typescript compiler starts a compile loop: It compiles the dist folder, which in turn creates another dist folder under the dist folder and it starts the process again. I can solve this adding `dist` to the exclude array, but I can't understand why this happens.

2) I'm using vscode, and I would love to use the compile on save directly within the editor, but it is not recognizing my tsconfig, not even creating a build task.

This is my repo structure

- Root

  - package.json
  - src
  - module 1
  - module 2
  - module-ts

    - tsconfig.json
    - src
    - dist
    - package.json

Comment: I'm not sure but your problem might be with allowJs. It might think the dist folder needs to be included as well after compiling the TS code. You could try moving the dist folder outside the module-ts folder and see if that stops it. Or setting allowJs to false. :)

Comment: Dear @toskv, as I said, I can just use the `exclude` option to exclude other folders, but it does not feel right.

Comment: your first question was asking why this was happening. I was saying it might be because of the allowJs feature. :)

Comment: Ok, to be fair you are right, the problem is the allowjs option. Now it would be ideal to have a solution to the problem too